# Can't find Reality Composer pro on Xcode developer tool

Tags: xcode, augmented-reality, realitykit, reality-composer

I just updated xcode 15.2 and I want to try to use Reality Composer Pro, I saw on the Apple developer video that it should be under Xcode -> developer tool -> Reality Composer Pro but when I open that I don't have Composer.

On the Apple webpage for Rality Composer is written "Reality Composer for macOS is bundled with Xcode, which is available on the Mac App Store."

Where i can find the Composer Pro?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right to be confused, as Apple is doing some funny business with Reality Composer, or Reality Composer Pro as it is lately referred to on macOS.

As of today it is still called Reality Composer on iOS & iPadOS and officially you can't get it for macOS.

In Xcode 11 you can find it in the top menu by navigating to `Xcode > Open Developer Tool` and you will see `Reality Composer`.
[Officially mentioned here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/creating-3d-content-with-reality-composer/#Get-the-Reality-Composer-App) as "...for Xcode 11 or later".
The "or later" part is only partially true.

In Xcode 15 and 15.1 there is no trace of it, but in **Xcode 15.2 beta** appears again as Reality Composer Pro, accessible from `Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Reality Composer Pro`. Somehow in support of the to be released visionOS.

It might be that Apple is migrating Reality Composer which they realised is not very user friendly (for everyone to understand what a .USDZ is and how to import various types of geometries, assign materials, add behaviours, etc.) to a Pro category. This would justify why Reality Composer projects do not work in Reality Composer Pro (the error says: ...project is not a valid Swift Package) and also why creating a new Reality Composer Pro project creates a Swift based project.

[Here Apple's official overview of these tools.](https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/tools/)

In a nut shell, as of today, you can not have access to Reality Composer on macOS (Sonoma) and no other way to get access to Reality Composer Pro unless you install Xcode **15.2 beta** (...and probably higher).